# What is the difference between java ObjectOutputStream and OutputStream?

Tags: java

I have an instance called u: User u = new User(name, password). If I use getBytes to every attributes of u and output them like output(It is a OutPutStream).write(u.name.getBytes()), is this a kind of serializable? What is the difference between ObjectOutputStream and OutputStream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OutputStream` is a base class for byte oriented java I/O ,`ObjectOutputStream` extends it . `ObjectOutputStream` is mainly used in serialization.

Comment: Can OutputStream be used as serialization like what I posted before?

Answer (score 0):

he Java ObjectOutputStream class (java.io.ObjectOutputStream) enables you to write Java objects to an OutputStream instead of just raw bytes. while outputstream is base class of all the output stream and enables you to only communicate with bytes.